# Is it possible for China (PRC) passport holders to receive a Multiple Journey Visa (MJV) for Singapore?

Tags: singapore, multiple-entry, chinese-citizens

Do you have a China (PRC) passport and did you receive a multiple journey-visa (MJV) for Singapore?

If you do, I would like to understand how you applied for it as there is no way to request single-entry, double-entry or multiple-entry on their form.

Comment: This release seems to indicate you get the MJV automatically if you are approved for a visa, so really no need for 1, 2, multiple check boxes on the application form - http://www.ica.gov.sg/news_details.aspx?nid=13456

Comment: @Tom care to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, according to this [release](https://www.ica.gov.sg/news_details.aspx?nid=13456). If you have previously visited Singapore and have been approved for the visa, you don't have to do anything extra, you'll automatically be granted the 10 year MJV. You'll note anyway that there's nowhere to request that on the [visa](http://www.mfa.gov.sg/content/dam/mfa/images/om/london/Forms/Form%2014A.pdf) form

> PRC nationals need not apply separately for a Multiple Journey Visa.
>   Eligible travellers will automatically be granted a visa validity
>   period of up to 10 years when they apply for a visa